Evaluating $\iint_R ye^x \,dA$ where $R=\{(x,y)|x^2 + y^2 \le 25, x\ge0, y\ge0\}$
Problem: Evaluate
$$I = 
\iint_R ye^x \,dA $$ where $R=\{(x,y)|x^2 + y^2 \le 25, x\ge0, y\ge0\}$
My attempt: The limits are easy to calculate. We integrate with respect to $r$ from $0$ to $5$ and $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi/2$. We also use the polar form so the integral becomes:
$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{5} r^2\sin\theta e^{r\cos\theta} \,dr\,d\theta$
I then separated the integrals with the outer integral having sin$\theta$ with respect to $\theta$ and the inner integral having the rest.
I computed the inner integral and got:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(  \frac{25e^{5\cos\theta}}{\cos\theta} - \frac{10e^{5\cos\theta}}{{\cos^2\theta}} + \frac{2e^{5\cos\theta}}{\cos^3\theta}\right) d\theta$$
I am not sure how to solve this integral now. Any help?

Hint polar: swap the order of integration

Hint other: do the integral in Cartesian directly

@NinadMunshi Ummm, in Cartesian with dx first, I get $\int e^{u^\frac12}du, u= 25-y^2$ or with dy first I get $\int \frac1w e^w dw, w=(25-y^2)^\frac12$.  Although, the 2nd is integrable with the Lambert function, why introduce Lambert when the polar integration below is much simpler?
Disclaimer: I haven't checked my work.

@nickalh The $dy$ integral you have is wrong. There should be no square roots anywhere which makes it the easier option. The $dx$ integral work you have is right, and $e^\sqrt{u}$ is integrable with only one extra substitution.

Switch order of integration:
$$I=\int_0^5 r^2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin \theta e^{r \cos \theta} \mathrm d \theta \mathrm dr=\int_0^5 r(e^r-1)\mathrm dr=4e^5-\frac{23}2  $$
